# when to use extended stored procedure instead of user defined stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008

when to use extended stored procedure instead of user defined stored procedure?
Whats the advantage of extended stored procedure and clr stored procedure

Comment: Can you explain what kind of task you feel justifies either of these approaches? Often people want to use CLR because someone said they should, not because there is an actual need.

Answer (score 1):

[Extended stored procedures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175200%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) let you create your own external routines in a programming language such as C.

Basically, non-SQL stuff. Obviously, normal stored procedures are all about SQL.

It's worth noting the following from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175200%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

> This feature will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL
>   Server. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to
>   modify applications that currently use this feature. Use CLR
>   Integration instead.

So it should be

> When to use [CLR integration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131089%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) instead of extended stored procedure?

And the answer from Microsoft would pretty much be: almost always!

Answer (score 0):

From SQL Server 2005+ don't use extended stored procedures as they are deprecated and poorly written ones can scribble on and corrupt other memory belonging to SQL Server.

I would only consider CLR procedures if it needed to do something CPU intensive that would benefit from being compiled code or had a requirement easier achieved with access to the CLR libraries (such as `System.Text.RegularExpressions`). Not for normal data access code as that is more efficient in TSQL.

From [next version of SQL Server](http://blogs.technet.com/b/dataplatforminsider/archive/2012/11/08/breakthrough-performance-with-in-memory-technologies.aspx) the use cases for CLR may be even less

> Today SQL Server’s query processor compiles queries and stored
>   procedures into a set of data structures which are evaluated by an
>   interpreter in SQL Server’s query processor. With Hekaton, queries and
>   procedural logic in T-SQL stored procedures are compiled directly into
>   machine code with aggressive optimizations applied at compilation
>   time. This allows the stored procedure to be executed at the speed of
>   native code.

Comment: I am likely to re-create the capability of extended stored procedures using CLR.  That way I can use my regular programming language, Delphi, to use my existing code base.  Seems silly to go through CLR, but oh well MSoft wants to force it on us.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO: never. Extended procedures have been deprecated for a long time and they certainly shouldn't be on any future development plans.

You should consider CLR whenever you find yourself wanting to use existing extended procedures, calling command-line stuff via `xp_cmdshell`, or otherwise operating outside of the boundaries of SQL Server. However in a lot of these cases you should also consider whether you really need to perform the task within SQL Server in the first place.

There are also some use cases where CLR excels at computational processes within SQL Server, such as [splitting strings](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings), but even there we can have [better workarounds that don't involve CLR](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-now-with-less-t-sql).

Answer (score 0):

For example, adding csv exports, pgp encryption, http or soap calls.  Basically to extend sql server so you can run more business process requirements inside it rather than using an external applications.